# asp.net c# scan application for code duplication - utility

Tags: c#, asp.net, redundancy

Do you guys by any chance know of a tool for visual studio that can scan the entire application and find code duplication?

I have to clean up a medium sized asp.net c# application and I am using "Find and Replace" but it is really tedious work. I was wondering if there was a utility or VS plug-in that could automate this process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204177/what-tool-to-find-code-duplicates-in-c-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give [Clone detective](http://clonedetectivevs.codeplex.com/) a try

Comment: Thanks Lucas! This looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html) can help.

From the homepage:

> Duplicate code can be hard to find, especially in a large project. But PMD's Copy/Paste Detector (CPD) can find it for you!

They have a [list](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/similar-projects.html) of similar projects.

Answer (score 0):

Simian is a good tool to use.  You can define code block size, and create an external command to run it inside of the VS IDE.

http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/

Answer (score 0):

It's not for VS, but Simian works pretty well.

http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/